# I am stuck in this question of finding the singular solution of the differential equation and reducing to Clairaut's equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

The question is $$y=2px+x^3p^2$$
Its solution is $$1+xy=0$$
And i have to find the singular solution after reducing it to Clairauts equation.
I have not reduced it to Clairaut's equation but i got to this step
[image: my version of solution to the question]

Comment: Please transfer to mathjax. Check that all terms are accounted for from one line to the next. // In what sense is this a Clairaut equation? Is there a factorization of the derivative equation modulo the original equation?

Comment: I know that i have not reduced it to Clairaut's equation but I have done another possible way to solve it. I am not getting any idea how to reduce it to Clairaut's equation

Comment: technically '$y=2px+x^3p^2$' is a statement not an interrogative...? what's going on?

Comment: i believe you must use mathjax/latex instead of just picture. i mean otherwise answerers are going to type from scratch instead of copy from your post

Comment: Is $p$ a shortcut $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$ ?

Comment: I was hinting that from the second to the third equation line you are somehow losing the term $3x^2p^2$, making all that follows invalid.

Comment: Yes p=dy/dx.....

Comment: Yes, I really had a serious mistake ...didn't notice that i lost the term $$3x^2p^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=2y'x+x^3y'^2$$
Can be reduced to [D'Alembert's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation).

Substitute $z=\dfrac 1x$:
$$y=2y'x+x^3y'^2$$
With  $p=\dfrac {dy}{dz}$:
$$y=-2zp+zp^2$$
$$y=z(p(p-2))$$
This DE is on the form:
$$y=zf(p)+g(p)$$

Comment: Is $p$ a shortcut $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$ ?

Comment: @BCLC  It is  $dy/dz=p$

Comment: P=dy/dx. Yes...